# How to keep the screen from going blank or locking for particular application

Tags: standby

Edited question:

Google Navigate app does have the logic to keep the screen from locking or backlight from switching-off, but a corporate BYOD software suite, I've had to install as my employer's policy, seems to lock-screen if an 'unknown application' is keeping screen unlocked/lit with no other activity detected (touch mostly!), after a timeout. Navigate is not on this software's goodbooks... So I was wondering if there is any app that can help me keep the backlight on and avoid the screen locking for google navigate ?

I am on Android JB 4.2 if that matters.

Comment: My Google Navigate most certainly does keep the screen on if I'm actually using the navigation. If I'm just looking at the route then it will go into standby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) for that:

- **Context:** App (select all apps to apply this to)
- **Task:** Keyguard off, display timeout to infinity (optionally add more, e.g. brightness settings)

Almost nothing that cannot be cured with *Tasker* :)

Comment: Does Tasker need rooting the phone ?

Comment: Not for that. It supports some "root-only stuff" as well, but that's optional.

Comment: PS: On more recent Android versions, you might need the *SecureSettings* plugin to disable Keyguard (on Kitkat, I needed to switch to that method).

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that it happens. My last few devices always stayed on while Navigating, when Navigation was a stand alone app and now that it is part of Google Maps. You could go to Settings > Display and turn the screen timout off. Double check the settings in Navigation.

Alternatively  [Screen timout toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chemdroid.screentimeouttoggle&hl=en_GB)  is an application on the Play Store that seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't like [RossC](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/40036/rossc)'s recommendation of Screen Timeout Toggle because it has a timeout, try [Keep Screen On](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nbondarchuk.android.keepscn). This app lets you define a list of apps to watch out for. If these apps are open, the screen is always on.

Previously, I used [Screen On](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.androiddev.ScreenOn), but it hasn't been updated in a long while, and it doesn't seem to work well with newer Android versions.